# Integral sign in LaTeX beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, integral

I am new to TeX Stackexchange and I do have a question. I hope that you can help me.

I am working with a `beamer` presentation and I prepare my Ti*k*Z pictures in a separate document (`article` class). I do get an integral sign via `\iint` like the following:

[image]

In my preparation document I get this by using the same code:

[image]

As you can see, the integral sign is not upright. The preparation document and the presentation use the same packages. Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

EDIT:

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, trans]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,pgf,amssymb,graphicx,commath,pifont,fancybox,setspace,multicol,mathtools,pgfplots}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xcolor,tabularx,fontawesome,empheq,epstopdf,circuitikz,mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$$\iint_A \vec{v}\circ\dif\vec{A}$$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to the answer of Henri Menke, he brought me to the idea to do something with the wasysym package. By using the wasysym package in this configuration, I got something like 'option clash'. By deleting wasysym, it works with no upright integral signs.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Which font do you use for your article document? Did you alreay try to use the same font for your beamer document? Maybe `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` is necessary, but without having a MWE this is hard to know.

Comment: Main issue is of course that beamer uses a different set of base fonts and thus text text and math look different. Any particular you don't just include the tikz directly into the beamer doc instead of precompiling them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `wasysym` package (as you do in your document).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \[ \iint \vec{v} \circ \mathsf{d}\vec{A} \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answers! The hint with the 'wasysym' package did work well.